# Selecting certain ids from SQL database and treating them differently than the rest

Tags: html, loops, for-loop, jinja2

I have a SQL table of categories, with columns id and name. Id # 1, 4, and 13 are "categories for the other categories". I made a for loop that makes a dropdown with all of the category names. I am trying to get categories # 1,4,13 to have the disabled attribute so only the subcategories can be pressed.

```sql
categories = db.execute("SELECT id, categoryname FROM categories")
```

```html
<form class="categoryselect">
        <select name="categorylist" id="categorylist">
            {% for category in categories %}
            <option value="{{category['id']}}">{{category['categoryname']}}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
</form>
```

Categories 1, 4, and 13 should not be pressable while the rest are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your query to

```
SELECT id, categoryname FROM categories WHERE id NOT IN (1, 4, 13)
```

This will not pull the categories that you don't want.

Comment: No problem. Best of luck

Comment: I will need to create two different for loops for both queries, how can I make the list still order from least to greatest by id?

Comment: You would add 'ORDER BY id asc' to the end of the query

Comment: the problem is, if I create two separate for loops the results of the first will output in order and then after the last one, the results for the second for loop will output. I think I will try adding a column that either has "disabled" or null inside it and set the attribute to that. Thanks for your help

Comment: Yeah you could do that, sorry I think I misunderstood your original question. I didn't realize you needed to still put the other categories. A disabled flag would work, or you can check for them in the front end in your loop (if id = 3, etc etc)